# JS - Same recurring statements in if-else

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this watcher in my `app.vue` that makes sure the right theme `attribute` is set on the `html` tag. I have a nested if/else loop, and as you can see in the code below I have two different conditions but two times the same statements.

Is there some way to code this is a more reusable way? I can imagine in some cases there are going to be more conditions with maybe the same statements.

```
  created() {
    const media = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

    this.$store.watch(
      (state) => {
        return state.settings.colorSettings.automatic;
      },
      (currentAutomaticValue) => {
        if (currentAutomaticValue) {
          media.addEventListener("change", this.setTheme);

          window.matchMedia &&
          window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches
            ? setThemeAttribute(themes.dark) // 1
            : setThemeAttribute(themes.default); // 2
        } else {
          media.removeEventListener("change", this.setTheme);

          this.colorSettings.darkMode
            ? setThemeAttribute(themes.dark) // 1
            : setThemeAttribute(themes.default); // 2
        }
      },
      { immediate: true }
    );
  },
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What does the method `setThemeAttribute` do?

Answer (score 2):

So you have a boolean, and from this boolean you go with either `themes.dark` or `themes.default`. Easy, extract a method that takes a boolean and properly calls `setThemeAttribute`.

```
function setThemeBoolean(bool) {
    setThemeAttribute(bool ? themes.dark : themes.default);
}
...
if (currentAutomaticValue) {
    media.addEventListener("change", this.setTheme);
    setThemeBoolean(window.matchMedia &&
      window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches);
} else {
    media.removeEventListener("change", this.setTheme);
    setThemeBoolean(this.colorSettings.darkMode);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I could come up with, but I'd recommend posting more context next time. I just have a feeling that you're not doing things in the most optimal way. I suspect the whole `this.$store.watch` might not be necessary.

Comment: Modern JS?? `matchMedia` has full support https://caniuse.com/matchmedia so no need to predicate its existence, you should use the optional chaining operator if needing to call an unknown. EG `matchMedia?.("foo").matches`, and  `window` is the default `globalThis` so its use is almost always redundant.  Thus the split line becomes `setThemeBoolean(matchMedia("foo").matches)`

Comment: @Blindman67 I just addressed the main question, I'd recommend you post your findings in another answer.